# How to change color of TOP BAR in PopOS?

Tags: linux, themes

I am new to PopOS! I have customized my desktop appearance except TOP BAR. I want to change this top bar panel. Is there any solution?

Comment: Not about programming or software development

Answer (score 1):

I have found the the solution with the installation of gnome tweak tools and extentions application. These makes the customization easier as it is on Ubuntu. I have also install plasma-desktop and from there I have installed all the themes I need. Without plasma desktop you can make the same but a bit  difficult.

- You can install gnome-tweak-tools from your shop where you get all the application.
- Again most of the case extensions application could be installed in your system. Other than you can install this from shop also like gnome-tweak-tools.
- In order to install plasma-desktop run this command on your terminal `sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop`
- Then restart your system and select plasma desktop while sign in with your account. You will see a gear button at bottom right of you sign in screen. From there you have to select them.
- In plasma desktop you have to go to settings and there you will get all the settings. For more customization you can follow YouTube tutorial.
- Then logout from plasma desktop and in you PopOS desktop open tweak application to select the theme from appearance section.

Here is my customization:

[image]